# sourcing .bashrc when starting emacs

Tags: ssh, source

I need to start ssh-agent so that I can use tramp within Emacs. However, if I start emacs via the start up menu, the environment (i.e. bashrc) does not seem to be sourced whereas when I start emacs from an open terminal it works just fine.

Is there a reason to that and how can I change this behaviour so that emacs does not close if I accidentally close my terminal -.-

Comment: no since I am using Linux

Comment: They are both Unix-like operating systems and environments work the same way in each.  I don't think you actually read the answer.  The greater point of difference is bash vs zsh, but the principles are the same and explain why things don't work the way you thought they should.

Comment: You can have a try with https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Answer (score 1):

The `~/.bashrc` file is read every time you start a shell, so only the shell and the programs started via the shell will have the configuration specified in `.bashrc`. When you start Emacs from the menu, your desktop environment spawns it. The desktop environment starts during login.

You can specify your configuration in `~/.profile` which is read during login.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained the cause of your problem.  This answer is aimed more directly at your actual use-case regarding `ssh-agent`...

I suggest using https://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo:Keychain as (a) it's very useful regardless, and (b) someone has already written https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/keychain-environment.el